# Shell: Delete filename.foo if filename.bar doesn't exist

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I want to check all JPGs in a directory (rf). If no WEBP file with the same filename exists > delete the JPG file.

Example:

- /a/1.jpg (ok)
- /a/1.webp
- /x/2.jpg (del)
- /x/3.jpg (ok)
- /x/3.webp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I won't give you the full script so you have a chance to figure it out and learn something. Here's how to chop off and append strings:

```
jpg="/a/1.jpg"
webp="${jpg%.jpg}.webp"
if ! test -f "$webp"; then rm -f -- "$jpg"; fi
```

Comment: Thanks. I was indeed lazy, but I didn#t know where to start at all. `webp="${jpg%.jpg}.webp"` did the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Jens:

```
#!/userbin/bash

for jpg in $(find /var/path/* -name '*.jpg')
do
    webp="${jpg%.jpg}.webp"

    if [ ! -f "$webp" ]; then
        rm $jpg;
    fi
done
```